# if $f $ is Bochner integrable function then $f$ is Pettis integrable.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(E,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a finite mesure space and $X$ be a Banach space. Take $f:E\to X$ be a mesurable function.

$*$ $f$ is **Bochner integrable** if 
$$
\int_{E}{\|f\|d\mu}<+\infty
$$
$*$ $f$ is **Pettis integrable** if:

- $x^*\circ f$ is integrable, for all $x^*\in X^*$.
- $\forall A\in \mathcal{A}$, $\exists f_A\in X$
  $$
  x^*(f_A)=\int_A{x^*\circ f d\mu}
  $$
  Why if $f $ is Bochner integrable function then $f$ is Pettis integrable?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to check if the two conditions for Pettis integrability hold for a Bochner integrable $f$?

Comment: yes, but I didn't understand how to show the second condition

Comment: Try considering $f_A := \int_A f d\mu$

Comment: I have already tried. Can we say that: $$\int_A x^*\circ f d\mu =x^*(\int_A fd\mu)$$

Comment: Yes. If you didn't already know that you should try to prove it from the definition of the Bochner integral.

Comment: Thank you very much sir :)

Comment: I think its usual to ask for $f$ to be almost separably valued when talking about Bochner integrable else "norm convergence" of $\int f$ doesn't work out so well.